# How much disk space do I need to upgrade Xcode on macOS Big Sur?

Tags: xcode, big-sur, disk-space

I'm on macOS Big Sur (11.2.3).  I would like to upgrade my Xcode to the latest version and have this disk space available

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5s1  234G   15G   30G  33% /
```

However when I go into the app store and attempt to upgrade, I get this message ...

[image]

Is this message a false flag?  Do I really need more then 30 GB to upgrade Xcode?

Comment: @fsb wouldn’t Big Sur be different? Doesn’t seem like a dupe to me.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy - it's a dupe because the answers on the original can be updated to include Big Sur; leaving a single reference point that other similar questions can be cross-linked to - overall making the answer easier to find.